# How to loop through database like asp style escaping html with using php

Tags: php, html

In asp i can loop through database very easily and visually escaping html (i don't know if i'm using the right term here) what i mean is that i don't want html embedded in my code while i'm looping through database because i like to make it clean and i think it looks better on certain editors (color codes). However I have no clue how to do this in php as i'm new to this. Plus with this technique i have below, i can do multiple while loops but i'm stuck on php because of the fact that i have to echo html inside the while loop and it gets confusing in every step. Here is what I have so you can understand better.

**i first make a database connection in asp**

```
    <%
Set bag=Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
yol=server.mappath("database.mdb")
bag.Open "DBQ="& yol & ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}"
%>
```

**then i create recordset**

```
 <%
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT * from data"
rs.Open sql, bag, 1, 3
%>
```

**then lets say i'm using table for my while loop**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>data header</th>
    </tr>
    <% do while not rs.eof %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=rs("datarowhere")%></td>
    </tr>
     <%rs.movenext
      loop %>
</table>
```

nice and clean i can see my html, i can see my data easily

NOW question is how do i do the same thing in php where html is completely separate not embedded in echo (assuming table name as data and row as datarowhere)? is it possible? if not what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to connect to a mysql database using the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) class in PHP:

```
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
  $rs = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

After you have your connection, you make your statement, [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) it, [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) it, and [retrieve](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) the results:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from data";
$sth = $rs->prepare($sql);

if ($sth->execute()) {
  $allRows = $sth->fetchAll();
} else {
  die('There was a problem with your database query.');
}
```

Then, in your HTML, you can loop over the section you want to add the information from the database to with a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop and echo the information there:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>data header</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($allRows as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["datarowhere"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
  ?>
</table>
```

You will have to see how the data is returned from the fetchAll() statement so you can properly access it an echo it out.

Here is the complete example:

```
<?php

/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
  $rs = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT * from data";
$sth = $rs->prepare($sql);

if ($sth->execute()) {
  $allRows = $sth->fetchAll();
} else {
  die('There was a problem with your database query.');
}

?>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>data header</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($allRows as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["datarowhere"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this was exactly what i was looking for thank you very much, didn't think it would be that easy once the connection is set.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>data header</th>
</tr>
<?php while (some condition) { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo 'something'; ?></td>
</tr>
 <?php
    }
 ?>
</table>
```

It seperates php and html code

Comment: I will also try while loop as well thank you for your kind respond.

Comment: @muratkh no worries bud :)